# Explicit expression for the fractional Laplacian of $1/(1+|x|^2)^s$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sobolev-spaces, fractional-calculus

For $s\in (0,1)$, is there are an explicit expression for
$$(-\Delta)^s \left(\frac{1}{\left(1+|x|^2\right)^s}\right)?$$

Edit: My goal is to show that for the function $u(x)=\frac{1}{\left(1+|x|^2\right)^s}$ defined on the ball $B(0,R)$ where $R>1$ we have $(-\Delta)^s u(x)\geq c(n,s) u^2(x)$ where $c(n,s)>0$ is constant dependent on $n$ and $s.$ Any references/hints on how to do this will be much appreciated.

Comment: In a comment to my answer you asked for an upper bound for $(-\Delta)^s u$, while now you seem to be concerned with the lower bound. Which is correct? (The lower bound should work unless the dimension is too low; intuition suggests that one needs $n > 4s$, but I did not even try to check it rigorously.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I apologize for not adding this before. I want a lower bound for the problem I am trying to solve. I work with the assumption that $n\geq 6s.$ I have been trying to use the integral representation for the fractional laplacian and the trouble comes when $|y|<2|x|$ because in the other case the integrand is positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I am making a typo, the result is:
$$ 2^{2s} \frac{\Gamma(\tfrac n2+s) \Gamma(2s)}{\Gamma(\tfrac n2)^2} {_2F_1}(\tfrac n2+s, 2s, \tfrac n2, -|x|^2), $$
where $n$ is the dimension and ${_2F_1}$ is the Gauss's hypergeometric function. See Table 1 on page 168 in my survey [1], or Corollary 2 in the original paper [2].

References:

[1] Mateusz Kwaśnicki, *Fractional Laplace Operator and its Properties*, in: A. Kochubei, Y. Luchko, *Handbook of Fractional Calculus with Applications. Volume 1: Basic Theory*, De Gruyter Reference, De Gruyter, Berlin, 2019, https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110571622-007

[2] Bartłomiej Dyda, Alexey Kuznetsov, Mateusz Kwaśnicki, *Fractional Laplace operator and Meijer G-function*, Constructive Approx. 45(3) (2017): 427–448, https://doi.org/10.1007/s00365-016-9336-4

---

*Edit:* The hypergeometric function is continuous on $(-\infty, 1)$, and — as described, for example, in [this DLMF entry](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.12#i) — we have
$$ {_2F_1}(a, b, c, -|x|^2) = \frac{p}{|x|^{2a}} \, {_2F_1}(a', b', c', |x|^{-2}) + \frac{q}{|x|^{2b}} \, {_2F_1}(a'', b'', c'', |x|^{-2}) $$
for some (explicit) constants $p, q, a', b', c', a'', b'', c''$. In particular,
$$ {_2F_1}(a, b, c, -|x|^2) \sim \frac{p}{|x|^{2a}} + \frac{q}{|x|^{2b}} $$
as $|x| \to \infty$. Therefore, as long as $n > 4s$, we have
$$ (-\Delta)^s [(1 + |x|^2)^{-2s}] \sim C_{n,s} |x|^{-4s} $$
as $|x| \to \infty$, for some (explicit) constant $C_{n,s}$. Obviously, $(-\Delta)^s [(1 + |x|^2)^{-2s}]$ is continuous, so we immediatiely get
$$ |(-\Delta)^s [(1 + |x|^2)^{-2s}]| \leqslant C_{n,s}' (1 + |x|^2)^{-2s} . $$
In order to get a similar lower bound, one needs to check that $C_{n,s} > 0$ (which seems to be the case when $n > 4s$, as long as I did not make any mistake), and that $(-\Delta)^s [(1 + |x|^2)^{-2s}]$ is never zero. I am no expert here, but [another DLMF entry](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.13) seems to suggest that the total number of zeroes of the hypergeometric function is $$\lfloor s \rfloor + \tfrac12 + \tfrac12 \operatorname{sign}(\Gamma(-s) \Gamma(2s) \Gamma(\tfrac n2+s) \Gamma(\tfrac n2-2s)) = 0 ,$$ as long as, again, $n > 4s$.

(Double check for typos.)

Comment: I remember this has been asked here before, but I cannot find the previous question. If you know where it is, feel free to add a link and mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to estimate these functions from above?

Comment: Sure, estimates of $_2F_1$ are well-known. This will be something like $c(n,s) (1+|x|^2)^{-2s}$ (unless $2s > n$, in which case the exponent is $-\tfrac n2-s$ rather than $-2s$).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, in my case $n>2s$. Could you suggest me a reference to obtain the estimate $c(n,s)(1+|x|^2)^{-2s}$?

Comment: [This DLMF entry](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.12#i) seems to be an option.

Comment: A added a comment that addresses your other questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. This is really helpful!

Comment: I did the computations and indeed the constant $C_{n,s}>0$ and the number of zeros is equal to $0$, one just needs to fix the expression for the number of zeros by adding 1/2 to the identity.

Comment: Great, thanks! I just corrected the one-half typo. If you spot anything else feel free to edit the post.

Comment: Sure will do, I had a quick question though. I don't the inequality is deduced from the continuity of the function. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question: if $f$ is continuous on $[0,\tfrac12]$, then it is bounded on this interval, and hence $|f(|x|^{-2})|$ is bounded on $\mathbb R^n \setminus B(0,2)$. Combined with the hypergeometric identity from the answer, this gives $|{_2F_1}(a,b,c,-|x|^2)|\leqslant C (|x|^{-2a} + |x|^{-2b})$ when $|x|\geqslant 2$. And, of course, ${_2F_1}(a,b,c,-|x|^2)$ is bounded on $B(0, 2)$. Does this answer your question?